# Check for dictionary defined word in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There is an xcode/objective C class

```
UIReferenceLibraryViewControl
```

that has a great method

```
+ (BOOL)dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:(NSString *)term
```

Is there a method in AS3 to check if a string is defined in the English dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as part of the standard library, you could try:

- [GoogleDictionary.as](http://code.google.com/p/googleas3api/source/browse/branches/GoogleAPI_v3_RC/src/be/boulevart/google/api/dictionary/GoogleDictionary.as?r=52)

Obviously this requires an internet connection.

Not definition-based, but there's also this:

- [Squiggly - Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/)